# I want to display list of data using java and angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc

> How to add list java in my Code angularJs for filter

**This is ProductController.java**

In this controller am returning `List` of data to UI.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")

    public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/ProductList")
    public String getProducts(Model model)
    {
        List<Product> products = productService.getProductList();
        model.addAttribute("products",products);
        return "productList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("viewProduct/{productId}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable int productId,Model model)throws IOException
    {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(productId);
        model.addAttribute(product);
        return "viewProduct";
    }

}
```

> Html and angularjs and out of this function is content of page Html not List

```
        <p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

        <p><input type="text" ng-model="products"></p>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in products | filter:products">
                {{ x }}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>


    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
            $http.get("/eMusicStore/product/ProductList/"+$scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
                console.log("success: " + data);
                $scope.products = products;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: In ng-repeat you need to use book instead of  products.

Comment: When calling the request from angular like this, you except a JSON string rather than a webpage right? But your Spring webpp sends a view(html) here. These client and server not matching.

Comment: Thx for help that's probleme how to send JSON from angularJs

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this one..hope it helps and make sense
<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="product"></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products | filter:product track by $index">
            {{ x }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("/eMusicStore/product/ProductList/"+$scope.cartId).
        then(function (result) {
            console.log("success: " + result.data);
            $scope.products = result.data;
        }, function(err){
           console.log('err',err);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: and if your api returns complete list of java then definitely my code will display the list of java..

Comment: How are you handling the HTML/VIEW response since the controller is returning JSP, not JSON?

Comment: Dont know what you want to achieve in this..and please provide a plunker so we can tackle easily..

Comment: thx for Help  yes is same my code and output is content page HTML not list of the products